Why String objects in Java not actual changes in main function when i pass them to a function and edit it in function like C++?
In C++ when i want to change string object by function .... i pass this by reference and any changes on object in this function I can observe this in main function for example:
void passByRef(std::string& word){
   word = "Ahmed";
}

int main(){
   std::string word = "Anas";
   passByRef(word); //Actual changes in this object (not take a copy)
   std::cout << word << std::endl; //Ahmed
return 0;
}  

But in Java the changes can't observed in main function with ordinary passing by reference
.. i must make an array of size 1 then pass this to function and edit on index ... Is there a way to edit string object like C++ directly?
public static void passByRef(String word){
   word = "Ahmed";
}

public static void main(String args[]){
   String word = "Anas";
   passByRef(word); 
   System.out.println(word); // Anas !
}


Because Java is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference.

And also because Java strings are immutable.

@k314159 Whether the string is immutable isn’t important when you reassign it anyway.

@KonradRudolph for someone coming to Java from C++, it's important to realise that strings are immutable. In the C++ code in this question, the contents of the string are changed, not what the variable is pointing to. This is possible because C++ strings are mutable. In Java, it's not possible.

@k314159 Even then it’s more important to realise that in C++ = is an operator that calls a member method, and that the code is therefore more like the Java code word.setValue("Ahmed"); than word = "Ahmed";. Because at the moment the behaviour would be the same for a mutable type (e.g. List<T>). So clearly (im)mutability isn’t the relevant distinction, and therefore a distraction.

Hello Anas, welcome, It is very easy to get confused, because in Java, “objects are passed by reference and primitives by value”, this statement (very frequent) lacks the clarification that when dealing with strings or primitive wrappers (String, Integer, Double, etc) these objects are passed by value.

std::string& word ← See that &?  Notice that Java does not have that.  That’s the difference.
